# conditionnal checkbox in react-native

Tags: react-native, checkbox, conditional-statements

I would like to have a little help please.
I am trying to create a condition.
If the product is in stock; the checkbox must be checked. If it isn't, it must be empty.
I fumble little by little and I get lost in my code. Could you give me a little help please?

Thank you for your help and your time.

here is part of the code (I know the condition is not correct at all, it's just a beginning of something) :

```
export default class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true,
      stock : true, 
    }
  };

...

     <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
       <CheckBox
          value={this.state.stock ? !this.state.checked}
          //onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
       />
       <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}>Stock</Text>
     </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <CheckBox
    value={this.state.stock}
    //onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: It's working fine! I'm sorry, it was more simple than I thought, thanks a lot !!

Comment: I take this opportunity to ask a second question. How do I do so that we cannot change the status by clicking the checkbox?

Comment: Wrap checkbox in view and make `pointerEvent "none"` like `<View pointerEvents="none"><Checkbox /></View>`